# Populate environment properties file using pom.xml proeprties

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

I want to fetch the artifactId from the pom.xml and use this artifactId to populate the properties file.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>xxxxx</groupId>
   <artifactId>fm-service</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <version>x.x.x-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

**application.preperties**

```
email.subject = "ALERT - [artifactId from pom.xml]"
```

Is is possible to do so? If yes how, if no, then please suggest alternatives.

Comment: Does the properties file exist already, or do you want to write it from scratch? Also, do you want to do it in maven, or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Yes the properties file exists and I want it in maven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maven provides a way to [filter resources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

First, the file `application.properties` has to be put into the `src/main/resources` directory. Then its content has to be:

```
email.subject = "ALERT - ${project.artifactId}"
```

Last (but not least) simply add this configuration to your POM:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Now all files in the resources directory will be filtered, which means that all variables inside are resolved.

Comment: <filtering>true</filtering> means exclude or include?

Comment: As the linked documentation ([Maven Filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)) describes, `<filtering>true</filtering>` means that all resource files are filtered before actually being put into the target directory.